# Creating shapes/lines from geo coordinates in postgis

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

Following the suggestion from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411760/creating-shapes-lines-from-geo-coordinates-in-postgis) I'm posting my question here.

I have a table in **postgres/postgis** with **geo data** and I want to show them on map via **qgis**.

Here is the table:

```
city  |  street  |  geo
A     |  A1      |  LINESTRING(17.257125 54.595952,17.253573 54.599437)
```

I do not know how to do this. I can show a single point on map (creating geo column with `AddGeometryColumn` function) without any problem, but how to show this part `LINESTRING(17.257125 54.595952,17.253573 54.599437)` (points with line between them). Any advices, suggestions or link to some articles about it?

I was thinking about splitting geo coordinates from `Linestring()`, but in the end this will not work at least that is my opinion.

I'm new to GIS things so please guide me.

Comment: to display the points (nodes) on a linestring check out this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177613/how-to-display-vertex-markers-in-qgis-for-non-editable-layers
if you want the nodes as features then you will have to create a separate layer like this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41923/how-to-extract-point-from-a-linemultilinestring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL / PostGIS (pgAdmin3) create a view and use **[ST_GeomFromText (text WKT)](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_GeomFromText.html)**:

- text WKT = geo;

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I found that for this case I create geometry column but forgot to fill it with data. Now when I'm trying to do this in the same way as with my table with points only I have error message:  `Error: parse error - invalid geometry HINT: "Linestring(LINESTRING(" <-- parse error at position 22 within geometry`.  This is my query: `UPDATE public.tablename SET geom = ST_GeomFromText('Linestring('|| x || ')',4269);` where x is the name of table with linestring data.

Comment: I did not understand, do you want to get a linear geometry starting from a points table?

Comment: Actually doesn't matter anymore. I had a mistake in data in table.  Data in Geo column were in format  `LINESTRING(17.257125 54.595952,17.253573 54.599437)`.  When I removed **LINESTRING**, **(** and **)** everything is working fine. So thank you very much for your support.