# Shifting overlapping lines with the same attributes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python

I have a layer of cables which overlap each other. I want to divide it so I can see them conserving their attributes.

I've just tried this method ([Shifting display of overlapping lines in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239129/shifting-display-of-overlapping-lines-in-qgis/268556#268556)), and it didn't help much because I can't select the lines, so I think maybe adding each line (with the new position) in a new shapefile, conserving the same attribute or by adding some instructions in the program code.

[image]

The only way I see for now is to really create different lines like in the picture above, with the same attribute.

---

it looks just like this but i can't select the lines or view its attributes
[image]

Comment: How does it look after you run the method you linked?

Comment: maybe you can render them this way https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221424/how-can-i-use-qgis-to-create-a-metro-style-map

Comment: @Rania ben othmen a few months ago I developped similar algorithm for the company I'm working for in the field of FTTH in paris, I can't help by publishing parts of the code here since it's the company's property, but if you want to talk business you can reach me on linkedin. I never done business with someone here before and I hope it's not against SE rules

Comment: The identify tool can be used for selecting one of several overlapping features. Click on the features with the identify tool, in the identify results window right click on the correct feature, then choose "Toggle feature selection."