# How do I make all polygon vertices show up even when vertex editor is turned off in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style, snapping, vertices

As I am digitizing a georeferenced map I'd like to always see all vertices rather than only when I hover my cursor over individual ones with snapping options turned on. I am making a lot of vertices so it is hard to find them all when trying to snap polygons as I draw them. I don't want to go into vertex editor because I am actively digitizing. How do I do this?

Comment: I found a similar workaround from: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177613/how-to-display-vertex-markers-in-qgis-for-non-editable-layers

Comment: For my mind adding marker line symbology is a solution, not a workaround.